# Draw lines inside the shape in p5.js

Tags: javascript, html, p5.js

js beginner and trying to make program which is change the shape of eyebrow.

I just finished to make shape by mousePressed event but I want to know how to draws lines inside the shape that I made!

Like the photo below, I made the shape of eyebrow by using p5.js functions (beginShape(), endShape(CLOSE)) but is it possible to draw lines inside the shape??

Any help appreciate!!

[image]

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <script src="p5/p5/p5.min.js"></script>
        <script src="sketch7.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>

var brows=[];
var browsFirst=[];
var flag=0;

function Brow(x,y){
    this.x=x;
    this.y=y;
    this.clicked=function(){
        vertex(this.x,this.y);
        noFill();
        ellipse(this.x, this.y, 8,8);
    }
}
function preload(){
    img=loadImage("faceSample.jpg");
}

function setup(){
    createCanvas(970,1334);
    image(img,0,0);

}

function fillColor(){
    fill(54,50,49,80);
}

function mousePressed(){

    brows.push(new Brow(mouseX,mouseY));

    if(brows.length==1){
        beginShape();
        brows[brows.length-1].clicked();
    }
    var d=dist(brows[0].x, brows[0].y, mouseX, mouseY);
    if(d>4){
        brows[brows.length-1].clicked();
    }else{
        flag=flag+1;
        fillColor();

        endShape(CLOSE);
        if(flag==2){
            print("Completed to make polygon");
            for(var i=0; i<brows.length; i++){
                browsFirst[i]=brows[i];
            }
            brows=[];
            flag=0;
        }

    }
    if(brows.length>1){
        line(brows[brows.length-1].x,brows[brows.length-1].y,brows[brows.length-2].x,brows[brows.length-2].y);
    }

}
```

Comment: but, where's your code? add that too in your question.

Comment: @ℊααnd I was planning to draw lines automatically according to the shape of eyebrow and simulate on screen. But If you help me to make by using an image, I don't mind :)

Comment: @ℊααnd That code is all I made...I was trying to transform the shape of eyebrow but I failed... so I wanted to draw lines first then I will find the way to transform the shape

Comment: but, did you run the code? it doesn't even draw anything on the canvas

Comment: @ℊααnd It's working. my code work when you click the mouse manually. I upload the photo

Comment: @ℊααnd you can click the mouse, then ellipse and line are created !!

Comment: check https://jsfiddle.net/9pa53ajm/ it doesn't do anything

Comment: @ℊααnd Because there is no html code and p5.js library!

Comment: @ℊααnd I will edit this post including html code as well

Comment: @ℊααnd Are you there...?